# Display custom template in ribbon in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, weblog

Just like Weblog Entry I want to display custom template so user can create content page directly from there.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set Insert Options on the standard values of the template for the Blog item to have a new custom template in that box.

Navigate to the Standard Values for the Blog template and click on the Assign button in the top Ribbon to add new templates.

Here's a post describing how to set this up in Sitecore pre 8, but the functionality is still exactly the same

http://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2015/2/how-to-configure-insert-options-in-sitecore-cms